# Why do my graphics drivers keep getting uninstalled?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, updates, graphics

I installed `nvidia-driver-455` via the [runfile on Nvidia's website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=2004&target_type=runfilelocal). It installs the driver plus several cuda packages.

After installing, the command `apt list --installed *nvidia*` will show `nvidia-driver-455` indicating that it was installed through apt. After a few days and some Ubuntu updates, my second monitor stopped working and the command `apt list --installed *nvidia*` no longer shows `nvidia-driver-455`.

I've seen people suggest that I disable updates, but that sounds extremely unsafe if vulnerabilities aren't patched.

Edit: Ubuntu 20.04, not a live system

Edit 2: I checked `/var/log/apt/history.log` and it shows `nvidia-driver-455` being installed, then purged on Nov 1, 2020 before I reinstalled it with the runfile linked above. It does not show it being reinstalled via the runfile and it does not show it being removed last night/this morning.

Edit 3: Edited again for length and clarity. Removed information that may have been irrelevant/misleading. The question is specifically focused on the disappearance of the graphics driver package `nvidia-driver-455`.

I want to know

1. Can I find out why it was uninstalled? Is there a log somewhere that should give me information on why this keep happening over and over?
2. Is this a known problem? Are there best practices for avoiding this that balance safety and not having my computer destroyed every few days? Is this a common problem on Ubuntu or on Linux in general? I've never seen this happen before on Windows or Mac and both of those also have automatic software updates.
3. Is Manjaro any better for this? I've been a fan of Ubuntu for a long time, but I'm unable work around this issue and I can't get any work done when I have to constantly reinstall my graphics drivers, which can itself be a very difficult process.

Comment: Updated with clarification. Ubuntu 20.04, not a live system

Comment: Since the 455 driver is not part of the standard repos, how are you getting it?  Via the graphics-driver ppa, direct from Nvidia,... ?

Comment: The most recent method I've used for installing the drivers is to first uninstall all nvidia packages from both apt and dpkg and then reboot, then use the `.run` file from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=2004&target_type=runfilelocal

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted? If you can't answer the question, just move on. Don't downvote me just for asking.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? You have apps installed for nvidia in docker containers, you're installing the driver thru a .run file and you're asking about a  nvidia  driver .deb that you think is missing...

Comment: @doug I don't know what you mean by the `.deb` being missing. I did install the nvidia driver and several cuda packages. The cuda part isn't directly relevant to this. After running the `.run` file, the command `apt list --installed *nvidia*` will show `nvidia-driver-455` indicating that the `.run` file installed it through apt. Then after a few days and some Ubuntu updates, my second monitor stops working and the command `apt list --installed *nvidia*` no longer shows `nvidia-driver-455`.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance, but I have an RTX 3080, which only works with 455 or newer

Comment: My mistake as you didn't have that information in your question.

Comment: The .run file does not install thru apt (a .deb package). nvidia-driver-455 is available in Ubuntu repos (-proposed) or thru the ppa. You should properly remove the driver you have via the .run and install the .deb package set..

Comment: @doug I guess I don't know what I can say that will convince you. I installed with the runfile and it showed up when I typed `apt list --installed *nvidia*`.

Comment: Apparently I do have to convince you because you're telling me that I'm wrong and the runfile didn't install it through apt, despite what I've seen to the contrary. I already tried the ppa approach. The first time I had this issue was using that ppa and doing `apt install nvidia-driver-455`. But I had the exact same issue that eventually they mysteriously disappeared and I had to reinstall them. The title of the question is why do the drivers keep getting uninstalled. If you can't answer the question, then please go away.

Comment: /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log??? Would it not make sense to blacklist all things *nvidia* in all methods of upgrades to ensure it is actually the upgrades?

Comment: @MikeMartin The new kernel version of `5.4.0-54-generic` now has the 455 driver with the `graphics-drivers` PPA.  In the new change log by running `apt changelog linux-headers-$(uname -r)` it reads:  `* Introduce the new NVIDIA 455 series (LP: #1902093)` `- [Packaging] NVIDIA -- Add the NVIDIA 455 driver`  In all honesty, I am not sure how you got the 455 driver installed before it got released to the repos as I didn't see it show up until I upgraded my kernel to the 5.4.0-54-generic.

Comment: Also, one other way it might have been removed is if you had a kernel update, but `dkms` was not installed to carry over the `nvidia-dkms` driver to the new kernel installation, which I don't think the driver direct from NVIDIA has the dkms.  I'll have to look deeper into that and see if that is correct.

Comment: @WU-TANG `cat /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log | grep nvidia` gives me nothing. I'm not sure how to blacklist all things nvidia in all methods of upgrades.

Comment: @MikeMartin Would you share the `/var/log/apt/history.log` & `/var/log/dpkg.log` , `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log` even part of it but include all sequential operations (from time break to another time break) not just nvidia related. add to question also  output of `apt-cache info nvidia-driver-455*; apt-cache policy nvidia-driver-455*`

Comment: @terrance ....that would be way too easy???? Has there been anything said to indicate that's not the most probable answer? I don't see the word dkms or kernel before you mentioned it. **Mike Martin - Did you include the dkms configuration during your install??? Do you have dkms installed???** Unless something has changed in the way nvidia/dkms works over the last bunch of years, I'm surprised it took this long for someone to mention it??? Am i missing something? I haven't dealt with installing nvidia in a minute.

Comment: Without seeing all of your logs, I can only point to: if your problem correlates with these dates http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux/ of your kernel, you may want to seriously consider @Terrance 's last comment. It's actually not at all unusual..... And if this is the problem, notice the last update, 3 days ago... you should be due for another reinstall, if you haven't already done it.

Comment: As near as I know, this one is pretty simple. When you install the .run package from Nvidia, it makes modifications to the kernel. Ubuntu is unaware of those changes and those changes will be overwritten when you update your kernel. The solution is to use the Ubuntu-packaged Nvidia proprietary drivers. There is no other solution, unless you want to keep maintaining the system by installing the drivers after every kernel update. I do not know enough about other distros (I don't need the proprietary drivers) to comment with any better offerings from other distros.

Comment: @KGIII I would think dkms would take care of that... (unless there is something different about ubuntu that I am not aware of) Install dkms....and Install the dkms module when the question is asked while installing the .run package.

Comment: @WU-TANG I've only used the packaged versions for a long time, but my understanding was that they didn't use, or at least properly use, [dkms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934009/how-to-repackage-nvidia-run-drivers-into-deb-with-dkms). The link mentions it and matches what I recollect, though it's old - and perhaps has changed?

Comment: @KGIII ..wow, that's 10 years ago... It's kinda hard to tell, but they wrote "they don't use DKMS", I can't tell if they mean ubuntu or NVIDIA. I'm leaning towards NVIDIA. With that said, I have never used a NVIDIA .run package that DID NOT ask me if I wanted to create a dkms module. And I can say with some confidence that I was not dealing with ubuntu in (the math seems to be) 2009... So my successful experiences came some time after. I can also say with some confidence that, in ubuntu, over the years I've done a bit of troubleshooting the nvidia dkms module it created (usually my fault).

Comment: @WU-TANG There's also [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual#Kernel_and_Mesa_Updates) which is entirely unhelpful with regards to the *why*. See this quote: "Every time a new kernel comes out you will probably have to manually rebuild the NVIDIA binary driver kernel module. This can be done by booting to the new kernel and then running: ..."

Comment: KGIII..... that one is referencing 2007/8... before my time with ubuntu. I can't speak for or against that. The bottom line (for me) would be... @MikeMartin , Do you have dkms installed? Did you answer 'yes' to install the dkms module when you installed the .run package??? If not or if you don't know, can you do that?

Comment: [Did you try to just `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Comment: @PabloBianchi Yes, I tried `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` before. I got the same result

Comment: I've seen `nvidia-dkms-455` in my installed packages list in the past. But I'm not sure whether or not it was installed most recently when I used the runfile method from Nvidia's website.

Comment: @MikeMartin the command would be `dkms status` should output "nvidia-XXX, x.x.x-kernel...." and also, I am foggy of this part, but I don't know if the the directory ever gets removed so it may still be in `ls /usr/src` proving it was at least once there(not sure that part would be helpful, need a timestamp of the directory)

Comment: Ahhh thank you! I already accepted the answer from @ognjen below, but I'll also make sure `nvidia-dkms-455` is installed and try checking `dkms status` to make sure it's working. It sounds like it probably was a kernel-related issue that hopefully dkms can solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about preventing apt from removing your package.

```
  echo nvidia* hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

But in this state you cant upgraded or anything like that. To remove hold status

```
 dpkg --clear-selections
```

Comment: Would this prevent me from receiving important security updates?

Comment: No it should just make that driver immortal. You wont be able to upgrade it but everything else should be good to go as is.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this answer and awarded the bounty. I don't know for sure yet if it will fully work and I think I won't know for several weeks/months because I can't reproduce it consistently. Thanks for helping. I'm hoping this fixes it permanently.

Comment: @MikeMartin I'm facing the exact issue you've described in your question and it's driving me crazy, did `hold` solve it? very interested to know whether it did or not, thanks